# search engine script that can index hash-fragment urls

Tags: php, html, search, hash

i was wondering if anyone had a link or tutorial for a search script that indexes urls with the # fragment. 
For instance my url 'mysite.com/#About/index' isnt recognised by search engines etc. But i was wondering if there is a script i can use in my website that will help visitors search through these urls?

Entering 'mysite.com/#About/index' into an address bar would return the single page interface with the dynamic content loaded into it already.

I might be thinkin way ahead of myself but maybe a search script that indexes all pages then before displaying results sticks a '#' after the first '/' and takes off the '.php' from the end. Is this even possible??

Able to use php jquery and mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this link to find out how you can make your content accessible to Google.

Google have established guidelines on this matter

http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/

http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: ive read this about a million times. i guess its a good starting point for others however.